# Makefile: why command substitution can't work in $(shell) function?

Tags: makefile

I have a variable in `Makefile`:

```
JAVABIN = $(shell dirname $(which java))
```

And when I echo the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `Makefile`, the variable definition complains:

```
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
```

When I quote the `$(which java)`, the `JAVABIN` is `.`, so the result is wrong. And I didn't understand how **make** reads a Makefile, maybe it is the cause. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar:

```
JAVABIN = $(shell dirname $$(which java))
```

See [6.1 Basics of Variable References](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference).

---

The specific error message you received was caused by the fact that the `$(which java)` piece expanded to the empty string, since it was an undefined variable. Hence the `dirname` system command ended up seeing no arguments, in which case it complains of a "missing operand".

Comment: Thank you very much, I have neglected it, but how the error occurs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.